# Wordpress URL not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using wordpress, i have some URL issue.

My current URL is IP address on server: http://www.192.10.1.22/states/?q=ohio

I want URL :http://www.192.10.1.22/states/ohio

> i used following code in functions.php file and it's working in my
>   local but when i upload in cpanel then it's now working given me error
>   page not found.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
      add_rewrite_rule(        
            'states/([^/]*)/?',        
            'index.php/states/?q=$1',        
            'top' );
    }

    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

i also used below code.

```
add_rewrite_tag('%states%', '([^&]+)');
global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'q' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'states/(\d*)$',
        'index.php/states?q=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
```

i also update permalink and apache mode_rewrite is also on.

so how could i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please Used Following code.
>
> First declare query var

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
global $wp;
$wp->add_query_var( 'q' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'states/(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=states&q=$1',
        'top'
    );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the rule in your .htaccess file on server.

```
    function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^states/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?q=$matches[1]','top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: i used directly that code in htaccess file but stile given me page not found.

Comment: Try adding index.php: RewriteRule ^states/([^/]*)/? /index.php/states/?q=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: still not found.

Comment: I updated my code , try the same with adding and without adding states after index.php

Comment: I used as per you said but it now given me 500  Internal Server Error.

Comment: Still given me page not found.i also updated permalink.

Comment: could you plz help me, how could this happen on server ?